# How do I implement in-app purchases with Expo?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

In the last few weeks I've been trying to implement a purchase system in my app - I've tried both revenuecat and glassfy without success.

In revenuecat (react-native-purchases) I got the error
"Cannot read property 'setupPurchases' of null"

And when trying with glassfy (react-native-glassfy-module) I got the error "The package 'react-native-glassfy-module' doesn't seem to be linked"

The application is written in REACT-NATIVE (js)

And all the settings (Google at this point) are accurate.

I would appreciate help or a recommendation on a way to implement a payment system in the application.

Thanks in advance.

revenuecat and glassfy without success.

In revenuecat (react-native-purchases) I got the error
"Cannot read property 'setupPurchases' of null"

And when trying with glassfy (react-native-glassfy-module) I got the error "The package 'react-native-glassfy-module' doesn't seem to be linked"

The application is written in REACT-NATIVE (js)